# Swift Array what happens when passing var that is nil to .contains and .filter

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, contains

I'm trying to understand some code in a project I'm working on.  I have an array property of strings:
`var names: [String]!`

```
func findName(name: String?) -> [Name]? {
    if name != nil {
        return nameManager.namesForSearchString(name)?.filter({self.names.contains($0.name)})
    } else { 
        return nameManager.allNames.filter({self.names.contains($0.name)}) //<-what get's returned here?
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is *if* the name *is* nil, what happens when .contains is called, and with *that*, what happens when .filter gets called?  This is implemented in a Favorites class, and I need to call this function to return all favorites if a button is tapped, so what would I pass to this function to ensure that all the contents of `Names: [Name]` are returned?

On a lower level, I want to understand how .contains and .filter work and what gets returned if nil is passed to them.

Another version of the same method from a different commit (that I also did not write) is this:

```
func findFavorites(name: String?) -> [Station]? {
        if name != nil {
            return nameManager.namesForSearchString(name)!.filter({contains(self.names, $0.objectId)})
        } else {
            return nameManager.allNames.filter({contains(self.names, $0.objectId)})
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is `name` declared? You can't pass `nil` to contains unless it is through an implicitly unwrapped optional which would just make it crash if it was `nil`.

Comment: You aren't unwrapping anything here.  My point was that the compiler doesn't let you pass `nil` to contains.  If you trick it into letting you by passing it an implicitly unwrapped optional then it crashes

Comment: I'm not even entirely sure how that compiles. I don't see `names` defined in that function, which means it's local and should be captured with `self.` Unless it's a global? In which case, is `names` of type `[Name]?`

Comment: @AlexPopov it's a property, I edited the code before posting.  Should have added `self.` and `self.names` is of type `[String]!`  I edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `name` parameter is *not used at all* in the else case. `$0.name` is a property of `$0` and unrelated to the local `name` variable.

Comment: okay, so say I have an array of names then.  I need to search the array for a name that gets passed to the function, and return all names if no name is passed.  what would that look like?

Comment: @jungledev Okay thanks. I'm in a playground now, and unless it was removed in Swift 2.2, `Array` only has a `contains` method that accepts a predicate `T -> Bool`, so I'm still confused as to how it compiles.

Comment: @AlexPopov I'm going to post a different version of the code from a different commit (neither of which I wrote).  Here: `if name != nil { return nameManager.namesForSearchString(name)!.filter({contains(self.names, $0.objectId)})
        } else {
            return nameManager.allNames.filter({contains(self.names, $0.objectId)})`

Comment: @AlexPopov the `contains` method that just takes an element is only available if your element type is `Equatable`

Comment: what is nameManager?

Comment: @dan ah, thanks. I'm in a Playground and minimally recreating the situation. That makes sense.

Comment: @ryantxr nameManager is an instance of the custom NameManager class, and for this question, isn't important

Comment: I beg to differ. Part of what SO is about is for others to use what we post at a later time. Someone looking at this later won't be able to follow the code. At least state what type `nameManager.namesForSearchString(name)` returns.

Comment: `nameManager.namesForSearchString(name)` returns an Array of objects that have name String properties

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to post a non-answer, but I do want this to be properly formatted so I guess a comment won't do. This might help you understand what's going on, and what happens with filter/contains. If you have any more questions, let me know, and I'll answer the question. If I'm completely off-base, let me know as well!

```
    // I don't know why this is implicitely unwrapped, as a nil in this Array crashes Playground execution
var localNames: [String!] = ["Troy", "Bob", "Donald"]

// I'm just modelling what I know about NameManager
struct NameManager {
  var allNames = [Name(name: "Bob"), Name(name: "Liz"), Name(name: "Anastasia")]
}

// I also assume the `name` in Name is a non-optional.
struct Name {
  var name: String = "some name"
}

var nameManager = NameManager()

func findName(name: String?) -> [Name]? {
  // Case where `name` is non-nil is excluded for demonstration purposes
  // I have expanded all the closure short-hands so we always see what we're doing.
  let allNames = nameManager.allNames
  // namesMatchingName is of type [Name], that we get by applying a filter.
  // `filter` works on a predicate basis: it goes through each element, one at a time,
  // and checks if it meets the "predicate", that is, a boolean 
  // condition that returns true or false. If it DOES meet the criteria, it will be included in
  let namesMatchingName = allNames.filter { (currentName) -> Bool in
    // Now we're inside the filter-predicate. What we do here is check if the `currentName`
    // is in `localNames`.
    let namesHasCurrentName = localNames.contains(currentName.name)
    // If the name IS in `localNames` we return true to the filter, 
    // which means it will be included in the final array, `namesMatchingName`.
    return namesHasCurrentName
  }
  // So now we have all the names that appear in both `nameManager.allNames` and `localNames`
  return namesMatchingName
}

findName(nil) // returns [{name: "Bob"}]
```